# Python transforms 0 to 0.693147180559945

Tags: python, r, binary, dummy-variable

I created a dataframe in R with a column that holds dummy variables (thus 1 or 0) and saved it to file using

`write.table(my_df,"my_df.txt",sep=" ", eol="\r\n", row.names=FALSE)`

Then, I read the file into Python using

```
with open('./my_df.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    my_df = myfile.read().splitlines()
```

Eventually, I want to do something with the column holding the dummy variable:

```
header = my_df[0].split(' ')
body = my_df[1:]
for i,j in enumerate(header):
    if j == '"dummy_variable_column"':
        column_index = i
dummies = [row.split(' ')[column_index].replace('"', '') for row in body]
```

This is an approach I often use. However, in this specific case some values in the variable `dummies`, in which the column of question is kept, are `0.693147180559945`. I cannot explain this to myself, there are only 0s and 1s supposed to be in the variable. Does somebody know what's going on?

*second edit (because of the comments)

This is the output of `print(my_df[:20])`

```
"subject" "session" "trial" "age" "gender" "dummy_variable_column"
"s1" 1 2 19 "female" 0
"s1" 1 4 19 "female" 0
"s1" 1 11 19 "female" 0
"s1" 1 14 19 "female" 1
"s1" 1 15 19 "female" 0
"s1" 1 16 19 "female" 0
"s1" 1 17 19 "female" 1
"s1" 1 21 19 "female" 0
"s1" 1 24 19 "female" 0
"s1" 1 26 19 "female" 0
"s1" 1 39 19 "female" 0
"s1" 1 40 19 "female" 0
"s1" 1 41 19 "female" 1
"s1" 1 45 19 "female" 0
"s1" 1 48 19 "female" 0
"s1" 1 49 19 "female" 0
"s1" 1 50 19 "female" 0
"s1" 1 59 19 "female" 1
"s1" 1 61 19 "female" 0
```

However, `print(my_df[37045])` does produce

```
"s20" 1 26 19 "male" 0.693147180559945
```

Furthermore, I would like to point out that in R after the command `unique(my_df$dummy_variable_column)` the following output is given: `0 1`

*third edits because of comments

This is how I work with my column:

```
header = my_df[0].split(' ')
body = my_df[1:]
for i,j in enumerate(header):
    if j == '"dummy_variable_column"':
        dummy_index = i
dummies = [item.split(' ')[dummy_index] for item in my_df]
```

And for instance `print(dummies[37044])` outputs `0.693147180559945`

Comment: What does `my_df.txt` look like? How does `text` get turned into `my_df`?

Comment: sorry, my fault. the file is read into my_df. The question is now up to date

Comment: Nothing in the Python code you show does anything except work with strings. Either there's code you aren't showing, or there's a fractional value in the file.

Comment: can you give us `my_df`, i.e. a [mcve]?  If you inspect the text file visually, what do you see?

Comment: in case it helps, that value is the natural log of 2: `print(log(2),digits=22)`

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using pandas to read mu_df.txt in python?

Comment: @chepner Please note my edit. The output in R clearly indicates that the column doesn't contain fractionals before it's written to file. Of course, I only show you the relevant parts of my srcripts. Other lines are not related to the problem in question

Comment: @DanielR Habits and subjective taste

Comment: You *haven't* shown the relevant parts of the script, because nothing in your code shows how `my_df` changes from a list of `str` values to (presumably) a dataframe.

Comment: I convert every column in ```my_df``` into lists of strings. Please note the third edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there is one column in the R dataframe, which consists of values such as `'re + ba'`. Because of the space, the split on spaces in the list comprehension `dummies = [item.split(' ')[dummy_index] for item in my_df]` (s. 3rd edit) does fail to grab the value from the correct column.